# "Page not found" after unfollowing someone on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Not only do I no longer see any of their posts, when I visit their page it says that it's "not found" which makes no sense unless they blocked me immediately after I unfollowed them.

Yeah, it's almost like I blocked myself from them by doing that. How do I undo the "unfollow" setting for that person?

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: How do I undo unfollowing this person?